# How can I save results of every game for a long time and compare new result with previous?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am making a game using SpriteBuilder + cocos2d-iphone v3. I made a global variable that stores a score during the game. But how can I save results of every time for a long time and compare new result with previous ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Core Data. This will allow you to save a record for each game, which you can later query, sort, and present in useful ways.

Another approach is to use NSUserDefaults. You can store an array like this:

```
// Set scores
NSArray *scores = @[@97, @76, @88];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:scores forKey:@"gameScores"];
// Get scores
scores = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"gameScores"];
```

This might be a reasonable approach to take if you only need to store limited data and don't want to use a database.

Answer (score -1):

You could use Core Data. There you can store Data and access it.